# How to bind the data of a Kendo Grid within a directive that has an isolate scope from the outside?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, kendo-ui, angularjs-scope, kendo-grid

Here is a picture of what I will be trying to explain.

### [image]

**Expected Results:** The directive (red) has a controller (red), and contains a directive (dark blue) along with an html table (green) that has a button (orange) in each row. The directive (dark blue) takes in an attribute, which it uses as the data for the Kendo grid (light blue). The value being passed to the attribute is dependent on what is selected in the html table (green).

Ex. If I have two rows in the html table (green) and I click on the first row, it is supposed to update the Kendo grid with the values from the first row.

**Current Results:** When I first click on the button (orange), the Kendo grid (light blue) will not update. When I click on the button for the second time, it will update, but with the data from the first click.

I tried to use $scope.$apply(), which cause the Kendo grid (light blue) to update, but I keep getting the error where $apply is already in progress.

**Question:** How do I get the Kendo grid to update properly without getting errors?

**Code:** Here is the HTML code for the html table (green).

```
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Age</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-ng-repeat="p in people">
    <td>{{p.name}}</td>
    <td>{{p.age}}</td>
    <td>
      <button data-ng-click="edit(p)">Edit</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the JavaScript code for the "edit" function used by the button (orange), which is part of the controller (red), along with the directive (red).

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('moduleA.RedDirective', [])

  .controller('RedDirectiveController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      //...   

      $scope.edit = function(p) {
        $scope.person = p;
        $scope.kendoDataSource.read();
      };

      //...

    }
  ])

  .directive('redDirective', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        //...
      },

      controller: 'RedDirectiveController',
      templateUrl: 'folder1/folder2/redDirective.html'
    }
  })

})();
```

Here is the JavaScript code for the directive (dark blue).

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('moduleA.common').directive('darkBlueDirective', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        person: '=',
        kendoDataSource: "="
      },
      controller: 'darkBlueDirectiveController',
      templateUrl: 'folder1/folder2/darkBlueDirective.html',
      replace: true
    }
  })
})();
```

Here is the JavaScript code for the datasource that is being passed to the Kendo grid (light blue)

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('moduleA.darkBlueDirective').controller(
    'DarkBlueController', [
      '$scope'

      function($scope) {
        $scope.kendoDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
          autoSync: true,
          transport: {
            read: function(e) {
              if ($scope.person) {
                e.success($scope.person);
              } else {
                e.success([]);
              }
            },
            create: function(e) {
              e.data.id = Date.now();
              if (!$scope.person) {
                $scope.person= [];
              }
              $scope.person.push(e.data);
              e.success(e.data);
              $scope.kendoDataSource.read();
            },
            update: function(e) {
              $scope.person[getArrayIndexByGridIndex(e.data.gridIndex)] = e.data;
              e.success();
              $scope.kendoDataSource.read();
            },
            destroy: function(e) {
              $scope.person.splice(getArrayIndexByGridIndex(e.data.gridIndex), 1);
              e.success();
              $scope.kendoDataSource.read();
              $scope.$apply();
            },
          },
          pageSize: 10,
          schema: {
            model: {
              id: "id",
              fields: {
                id: {
                  editable: false,
                  type: "string"
                }
              }
            },
            total: function(response) {
              return response.length;
            }
          }
        });
        //...
      }
    ]);
})();
```

Here is the HTML code for the Kendo grid (light blue).

```
<div class="kendo-grid-content" kendo-grid id="lightBlueGrid" k-data-source="kendoDataSource" k-selectable="'row'" k-filterable="{
                         extra : false,
                         messages : {
                         info : 'Filter by: '
                         },
                         operators : {
                         string : {
                         contains : 'Contains'
                         }
                         }
                         }" k-sortable="'single'" k-resizable="true" k-pageable='{
                                    pageSize : 10,
                                    refresh : true
                                }' k-columns="[ {
                                field : 'id',
                                title : 'Id'
                            }, {
                                command : [ {
                                    name : 'destroy',
                                    text : 'Remove'
                                } ],
                                width : 120
                            } ]" k-editable="{
                                    confirmation : false
                                }" k-on-change="lightBlueGridOnChange(kendoEvent)" ng-show="!isLightBlueGridEmpty()"></div>
```

Hope this isn't too confusing to understand.